# Domain level session cookie on multiple domains

Tags: jakarta-ee, coldfusion, jrun

If you want ColdFusion to create your session cookie as a domain level cookie e.g. .bar.com rather than foo.bar.com then you can configure that in the jrun-web.xml:-

```
<session-config>    
   <cookie-config>
          <active>true</active>
          <cookie-domain>.bar.com</cookie-domain>
   </cookie-config>
  <persistence-config>
    <active>false</active>
  </persistence-config>
</session-config>
```

However, this is an instance wide setting so if you want to run two applications on that instance or indeed one application with or more different top-level domains then one of them will have sessions that do not work.

Is there a way to add multiple domains to the jrun-web.xml and have it pick the relevant one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find [the DTD for jrun-web.xml](http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/descriptordocs/dtds/jrun-web.dtd.txt) (the link @ the top points to a defunct Macromedia URL).

This specifies that there can be only one `<cookie-domain>` node in the XML. I've also tested a list of domain names, eg:

```
<cookie-domain>.domainA.com,.domainB.com</cookie-domain>
```

And that doesn't work either.

Not an absolute answer, but I suspect that it's possibly not possible (!), and it's certainly not possible via jrun-web.xml (which I guess answers one of your questions at least).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `<CFHEADER>` to set domain cookies instead of `<CFCOOKIE>`?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could use CFHEADER to manipulate the cookies that were created by cfapplication.  Maybe post an example you've seen work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfapplication
   setdomaincookies=yes
   .....>
```

This will set your cfid and cftoken cookies as domain cookies (*.bar.com) rather than the host-specific values (foo.bar.com).

[CFApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d69.html) (see the section on setDomainCookies)

Comment: this only affects CFID and CFTOKEN sadly. We are using J2EE sessions which are unaffected by this setting.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you name your application with the cgi.server_name variable, and each of your sites uses the same application.cfc or application.cfm file, then your session and cookie variables will be properly scoped for each individual site. For example:

```
<cfapplication name="#cgi.server_name#" sessionmanagement="YES" clientmanagement="YES" sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#" applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#"  clientstorage="COOKIE" setclientcookies="YES">
```