# sharing session in web applications

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I am developing A Web Application using `JSP` & `Servlets` (Container: `Tomcat7`, Database: `Oracle10`)

I have developed some web applications like `Profile`, `Reports`, `Leads`. Then I have developed A `Login` application. In this application I am storing *USERID* in `Session` with some more session attributes.

After user logs in he will be shown menu which contains links to other Applications like links to `Profile` Application.

So when I access `Session` after user log in:

- If I try to access session withing the same application(Login) then I get session with all the required attributes
- But when I try to access session from other applications like
  `Profiles` then I get session as `null`

**code snippet to check session** (Servlet Filter in Login web application)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session==null)
{
    System.out.println("Session does not exist... Redirected to LOGIN Page.");
    response.sendRedirect("/ApplicationName/Login.jsp");
}
```

I am accessing session in `Profile` application to check whether user is logged in or not.

Then I have searched, and I have found that `Session` can't be accessed from other applications for security reasons.(I have also found that it can be done by setting `crossContext="true"`)

Then I have found other option like making `EAR` of all applications and then deploy it, but unfortunately `EAR` it is not supported by `Tomcat7`.

I am new to web environment, so if anyone has worked on this before then please let me know what can be the options?

Thanks in advance

**Update1**

Now I have decided to use `EAR`, in which I will pack all `WAR` files and then I will try to share session between them. since Tomcat doesn't support `EAR` I have installed `Oracle Glassfish`, Then I have created `Enterprise Application Project` which contains two Applications `1. Login` and `2. Profiles`, and then created `EAR` file, and deployed it on `Glassfish`.
So I want to share session between those two applications(on Glassfish), so if anybody has any idea about it then please let me know. (link to any tutorial will also be appreciated)

Comment: means you want to share data between several application running on same web server. This you can do with some manipulation in web servers Catalina. I don't think there will be another method for doing this,

Comment: @Nikhil yes, i want to share data between several applications running on same web server(tomcat7)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293350/domain-level-session-cookie-on-multiple-domains keywords: domain level session cookies

Comment: single sign on may help you

Comment: I think you need to re-consider your architecture. Login should not be an application. It should be a module or service that your application uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I have seen this done in my shop is to stuff the login credentials into an encrypted cookie and install agents (java filters, web servers mods etc, in front of the applications that need the user data) that will decrypt the cookies and pass along the data to the downstream applications. Do not store login information in HTTP session if you want to share it across applications.

Comment: @GaborSch can you elaborate why you think its hacky? If the web applications are running on different domains and user identities are totally not related, then I would consider putting in a full SSO solution. But if your applications are all on the same domain, I don't see any issues with this approach.

Comment: I wouldn't store any user credentials in a session cookie, either encrypted or not. That's a potential security vulnerability; though if you're encrypting with an assymetric encoding that may be fine. Anyway, IMHO that would involve too many components.

Comment: Use [Kerboros](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/) to handle this for you. Why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @GaborSch Anything that you propagate through the browser is going to be vulnerable (SSL or not). There are many ways to make it secure. Like for e.g. storing a opaque reference to the user id and map it back to actual ids downstream ..etc. From a complexity perspective, setting up a good encryption framework is not anymore complex than setting up a SSO framework. In fact, a good encryption framework is essential for SSO (SAML, OAuth etc.)

Comment: @GaborSch poster is clearly describing symmetric encryption as he is referring to filters that "will decrypt the cookies". I am sorry but this makes no sense. What cryptographic keys will the filters use to decrypt the cookies? Are the keys hardcoded in the filters' implementation?

Answer (score 5):

As pointed above, the requirement you talking about is Single Sign On (SSO). The simplest SSO that you  can implement is the following:

1. After the successful authentication add the cookie with the encrypted user name (you do not need to encrypt a password)
2. If you access any of your application with the user name cookie and success to decrypt it, it means that a user was authenticated and you should not show the login page.

Use AES-256 for the encryption.