# make servlet filter applicable for all web applications in EAR

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish, servlet-filters, servlets

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlets.

I have developed a servlet filter for Login purpose. Which checks whether user is logged in or not, if user is logged in then it allows access to the requested resource, else it redirects request to the Login page. And it works perfectly.

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myfilter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PARAM_NAME_HERE</param-name>
        <param-value>PARAM_VALUES_HERE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If I put above code in `Tomcat`  **Home-> conf-> Web.xml** then the filter was applicable for all the applications deployed in `Tomcat`.(This is what I want to achieve in Glassfish for a EAR file)

But now for [some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16060390/1551233) I have decided to shift to Glassfish. And now I have created A `EAR` file which contains two applications(WAR) `1.Login` and `2. Profiles`. Filter is in `com.filter` package which is in `Login Application` and not present in `Profiles`.

My question is that where should I put above `XML` code, which will make sure that the filter is applicable for All applications(WARs) in the `EAR`?

**Update1**

If I put above XML code in `defualt-web.xml` which is under the directory `glassfish\domains\domain1\config\` then it is applicable for `Login` Applicaion but not for the `Profiles` application which is in the same `EAR` file.

There is Error in the log:
Exception starting filter MyFilterName java.lang.InstantiationException
.....
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myfilter.MyFilterName

[Note: Filter is in the `Login` application(WAR) and not in the `Profiles` application(WAR)]

So how should I make this applicable to `Profiles`(all WARs in EAR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jar contains your filter into `glassfish\domains\domain1\lib` folder