# How to get logout from different Java Web application using Java HTTP Post Request

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, http-post, session-state

I have 3 web projects(Java) **M1** **M2** and **M3**. I am sending request and getting response using `HTTP POST` request.

I am trying to implement `Single Sign-Off`. If I logout from one application then rest of application automatically got logoutted.

I tried with session ids but its not working, Because HTTP Post session less. Here is my code:

```
HttpSessionContext sc = request.getSession().getSessionContext();
HttpSession session = sc.getSession(sessionId);
session.invalidate();
```

Using above code I am getting session object of application and invalidate them.

Comment: Have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060390/sharing-session-in-web-applications

Comment: @JunedAhsan Thanks, But its not useful.